# Possible to suppress "String continuations are not recommended" warning in Google Closure?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, ecmascript-5

See http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.4 - LineContinuation syntax.

E.g. -

```
var K = '\
Some very \
long text.'
```

Is there a magic key/flag for the @suppress {...} annotation on a function to make the Google Closure compiler STFU about its style guide on this ("String continuations are not recommended")?  Even better would be a global configuration to suppress this particular warning.

I found the @suppress documentation, but there are many flags:  https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Warnings
(neither conformanceViolations nor suspiciousCode were the right thing, and it's hard to tell from the list if this case is even covered)

I don't work at Google, and I don't care if they don't like multi-line strings with backslash instead of quote-plus-quote (since it works for what I use it, inter-line spaces and all, even on IE11).  Anybody able to work around this noise w/out changing the source code?

Thanks.

Comment: you can use template strings.

Comment: Thanks, but then I have to go up from ES 5 (5.1) to ES 2015.  I'm not committed to using Closure as a transpiler yet, vs just concatenating the files w/out any processing.